# ¿Cómo prevenir que un cuadro de diálogo aparezca fuera del límite del escritorio en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un dialogo en **WPF** que cuando lo abren por primera vez aparece en el centro de la pantalla.

Para permitir al usuario la modificación del layout; al cerrar el diálogo guardo en un XML la posición de donde estaba (`Top` & `Left`) así como las medidas de ancho (`ActualWidth`) y alto (`ActualHeight`).

El problema esta en siguiente caso (Tengo más de un monitor):

- Abro el diálogo y lo colocó en un monitor secundario y luego lo
  cierro, las posiciones se actualizan.
- Desconecto el monitor secundario.
- Abro el diálogo de nuevo, pero de acuerdo a las posiciones guardadas en el **XML** aparece como no visible.

¿Hay alguna forma de detectar nativa de **WPF** si el diálogo quedará no visible para el usuario?, si es asi, ¿Como puedo detectarlo y obtener la posición correcta donde mostrarlo?

**Edicion**

De forma manual esta es la solucion que tengo actualmente:

```
var maxWidth = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
var maxHeight = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;

var lastTop = Convert.ToDouble(xml.getValue("Dialog_Top"));
var lastLeft = Convert.ToDouble(xml.getValue("Dialog_Left"));

if (lastTop >= maxHeight || lastLeft >= maxWidth || lastTop == 0 || lastLeft == 0)
{
    if(WindowStartupLocation != WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner)
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
}
else
{
    if(WindowStartupLocation != WindowStartupLocation.Manual)
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

    Top = lastTop;
    Left = lastLeft;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que lo que debes hacer es antes de abrir la ventana, debes revisar el tamaño de la pantalla actual, y si los valores almacenados en el XML son mayores a los valores detectados, ubica la ventana en una posición por defecto.

Comment: Cuando lo abres podrías hacer una simple comprobación para saber algunas cosas que pueden ayudarte, por ejemplo si hay 1 o 2 monitores (o 3 o 4) y si están en modo extendido, duplicado, una pantalla, etc.. y así determinar los recursos que tienes activos, luego si hay 1 monitor restaurar la posición del cuadro a la posición central, del primer monitor disponible, imagino que con WMI puede ser sencillo.

En resumen, no solo leer la posición desde el XML sino comprobar si esa información es posible aplicarla..

Comment: Si, habia pensado eso, pero pense que WPF pudiera tener alguna funcion que comprobara eso. De hecho tengo parte de esa comprobacion manual, aunque sigo experimentando unos bugs.